# Can we use Variable loadings from Multi Factor Analysis to define the variable importance

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I wanted to know more in-depth about drawing the relationship between variable loadings that we get from Multi-Factor Analysis to variable importance. In other words, for what purposes can we use variable loadings from MFA?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you referring to exploratory or confirmatory factor analysis? Standardized or unstandardized loadings? Also, pretty much any introductory textbook on factor analysis and/or structural equation modeling will provide you with a discussion of the meaning and interpretation of factor loadings.